# Android: how to click on polyline API v2

Tags: android, maps, polyline

I would like to click on different polylines. I do not see any documented clickable events for polylines in android.

I found a solution with `map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {`

I just get the polyline `LatLng` and search for real click coordinates on the map.

The new changes is in the code.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

code:

```
//Polyline
private class GetRouteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



    String response = "";

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    public void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RazhodCenaGoogleMaps2.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Calculating directions");
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //Get All Route values


        v2GetRouteDirection = new GMapV2DirectionGoogle();

        document = v2GetRouteDirection.getDocument(latLngFrom, latLngTo,  GMapV2DirectionGoogle.MODE_DRIVING);

        response = "Success";
        return response;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();


 final PolylineOptions rectLine1 = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true);
 final PolylineOptions rectLine2 = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.GRAY).geodesic(true);
 final PolylineOptions rectLine3 = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.GRAY).geodesic(true);

 ArrayList<Integer> Count = v2GetRouteDirection.CountPoly(document);

      for(j = 0; j < Routes.size(); j++ ) {

             if (j == 0) {

                    ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint1 = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection1(document);

                    for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint1.size(); i++) {
                        LatLng point1 = directionPoint1.get(i);
                        rectLine1.add(point1);


                    }

                    // Adding route on the map
                    map.addPolyline(rectLine1);
                }

             if (j == 1) {

                    ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint2 = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection2(document);

                    for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint2.size(); i++) {
                        LatLng point2 = directionPoint2.get(i);
                        rectLine2.add(point2);


                    }

                    // Adding route on the map
                    map.addPolyline(rectLine2);
                }

              if (j == 2) {

                    ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint3 = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection3(document);

                    for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint3.size(); i++) {
                        LatLng point3 = directionPoint3.get(i);
                        rectLine3.add(point3);


                    }

                    // Adding route on the map
                    map.addPolyline(rectLine3);

                }

            //new code
            final PolylineOptions rectLine11 = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
            final PolylineOptions rectLine21 = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.GREEN).geodesic(true);
            final PolylineOptions rectLine31 = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLACK).geodesic(true);

      //searching for roads
      ArrayList<Integer> Count1 = v2GetRouteDirection.CountPoly(document);

            int j1;


            int k = -1;
            int p = 0;
            int c = 0;
            for(j1 = 0; j1 < Count1.size(); j1++ ) {


                if (j1 == 0) {
                    k = 0;

                }


                if(j1 == 1){
                    p = 1;
                }


                    if (j1 == 2) {
                        c = 2;
                    }

                }



            final int finalK = k;
            final int finalC = c;
            final int finalP = p;

        //new code
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    latTouch1 = point.latitude;
                    lonTouch1 = point.longitude;

                    //Remove decimal from coordinates
                    DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

                    String formattedLat = nf.format(latTouch1);
                    String formattedLon = nf.format(lonTouch1);

                    double latTouch = Double.parseDouble(formattedLat);
                    double lonTouch = Double.parseDouble(formattedLon);


                    LatLng touch = new LatLng(latTouch, lonTouch);


                    if (finalK == 0) {


                        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint11 = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection1(document);

                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < directionPoint11.size(); i1++) {
                            LatLng point11 = directionPoint11.get(i1);

                            Double latlng1 = point11.latitude;
                            Double latlng2 = point11.longitude;

                            String formattedLatLng1 = nf.format(latlng1);
                            String formattedLatLng2 = nf.format(latlng2);

                            double pointDouble1 = Double.parseDouble(formattedLatLng1);
                            double pointDouble2 = Double.parseDouble(formattedLatLng2);

                            LatLng point111 = new LatLng(pointDouble1, pointDouble2);


                            //check if poly is equal to the real coordinates
                            if (point111.equals(touch)) {


                                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint1 = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection1(document);

                                for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint1.size(); i++) {
                                    LatLng point1 = directionPoint1.get(i);
                                    rectLine11.add(point1);


                                }

                                // Adding route on the map
                                map.addPolyline(rectLine11);

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Polyline 1 founded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    }



                   if (finalP == 1) {

                        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint21 = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection2(document);

                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < directionPoint21.size(); i1++) {
                            LatLng point11 = directionPoint21.get(i1);

                            Double latlng1 = point11.latitude;
                            Double latlng2 = point11.longitude;

                            String formattedLatLng1 = nf.format(latlng1);
                            String formattedLatLng2 = nf.format(latlng2);

                            double pointDouble1 = Double.parseDouble(formattedLatLng1);
                            double pointDouble2 = Double.parseDouble(formattedLatLng2);

                            LatLng point111 = new LatLng(pointDouble1, pointDouble2);


                            if (point111.equals(touch)) {


                                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint2 = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection2(document);

                                for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint2.size(); i++) {
                                    LatLng point2 = directionPoint2.get(i);
                                    rectLine21.add(point2);


                                }

                                // Adding route on the map
                                map.addPolyline(rectLine21);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Polyline 2 founded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;

                            }

                        }
                    }




               if (finalC == 2) {

                        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint31 = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection3(document);

                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < directionPoint31.size(); i1++) {
                            LatLng point11 = directionPoint31.get(i1);

                            Double latlng1 = point11.latitude;
                            Double latlng2 = point11.longitude;

                            String formattedLatLng1 = nf.format(latlng1);
                            String formattedLatLng2 = nf.format(latlng2);

                            double pointDouble1 = Double.parseDouble(formattedLatLng1);
                            double pointDouble2 = Double.parseDouble(formattedLatLng2);

                            LatLng point111 = new LatLng(pointDouble1, pointDouble2);


                            if (point111.equals(touch)) {


                                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint3 = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection3(document);

                                for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint3.size(); i++) {
                                    LatLng point3 = directionPoint3.get(i);
                                    rectLine31.add(point3);


                                }

                                // Adding route on the map
                                map.addPolyline(rectLine31);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Polyline 3 founded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;

                            }

                      }
                   }
                }

            });

           }

      }
```